# MySQL Query i'm stumped over

Tags: mysql

I did a test today and there were 2 questions I couldn't figure out. I forgot the second one, but here is the first:

You have a database about beer. Three tables, only 2 relevant to the question. These are:

Variaties:

- variety_id
- variety_name

Beers:

- beer_id
- beer_name
- variety_id
- beer_alcohol

beer_alcohol is a double, representing the alcohol percentage.

There were 38 varieties of beer and 1215 individual beer entries.

The question was: Display all individual varieties of beer, per variety the highest alcohol percentage and also the name of the beer that has this percentage.

At first sight, this is an "inner join" on the variety_id, a "max()" on the alcohol and a "group by" on the variety_id/variety_name.

The problem is, this won't display the name of the beer with the highest % alcohol of it's variety. It will display the alphabetically first beer of its variety.

And I cracked my head over it but I can't begin to image how to do this without a function.
Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Beer databases? Am I the only one working on boring finance stuff? :)

Comment: I think you're almost there. You would need to group by the beer name as well

Comment: Join again to the beers table using beer_alcohol and variety_id, I should think.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella sorry, that produces the entire list of beers, not just 1 per variety

Answer (score 0):

do one more join which joins on varietyid and %. doing this on the outside gets the correct info.

this will bring 2 results back if there are beers with equal percentages

Answer (score 0):

You could also sub-select, eg

```
select variety_id, variety_name, beer_name, abv
FROM varieties
JOIN (
  select beer_id, beer_name, variety_id, MAX(beer_alcohol) as abv
  FROM beers
  GROUP BY variety_id
) booziest ON booziest.variety_id = varieties.variety_id
```

Comment: this query, for me always give beer_id, beer_name of first record, but variety_id and abv of correct desire record. To over come this you must include the beer_name and beer_id in group by...

Comment: Yes, thanks - the grouping behavior in MySQL is a little fuzzy in this case and I'm being lazy by not specifying.  To do grouping right you should specify every column selected that is not an aggregate, in this case the beer_id and beer_name

Comment: Sorry, but the result is the same. Each beer_name displayed is the first of its variety, alphabetically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to have sample data and sample output but let's blindly answer the question.

This is a greatest-n-per-group question (with n = 1). You can solve this with a derived table with a group by or, my personal favourite, the left join:

```
SELECT v.variety_id, v.variety_name, b1.* FROM beers b1
LEFT JOIN beers b2
  ON b1.variety_id = b2.variety_id AND b1.beer_alcohol < b2.beer_alcohol
WHERE b2.beer_alcohol IS NULL
JOIN varieties v ON b1.variety_id = v.variety_id
```

Comment: I'm getting an "error in the SQL syntax" for the last line. I switched it with the 2nd to last line and it gave a result of 168 rows. This probably has to do with the query not including any form of grouping. Thanks for trying to help though.